# Some of my php is rendered only when logged as admin

Tags: plugins, php

I am using the al-in-one-calendar plugin, and have my own theme for the calendar which worked fine before updating the plugin.

In the month view of the theme I am displaying the calendar view and above it the navigation links (The brown area with the white arrows).

[image: When logged as admin]

**The way it should look (And indeed looks like when I am logged in as admin)**

**NOW**
The wired thing is that the navigation does load when I am connected as admin, but just disappear when disconnecting. (I have no condition that does that)
 [image: When logged out]

**The What I looks when I am logged out**

it is looks like the php is not rendered at all, I can not see any trace of the code in the source.

How could that be ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any if( is_admin() ) condition in the code which is restricting to execute php code for non admin users?

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: Check that you do not have a Caching plugin (like wp super cache). They typically disable the cache for Administrators, only for unidentified (unlogged) users.

Comment: Does the calendar work with a default calendar theme or if you use a default WordPress theme?

Comment: Can you give us a test URL? Have you checked if the missing links are being rendered in the HTML source code?

Perhaps they are in the HTML but they are not visible due to some JS or CSS issue.